# Unable to access "this" inside an object litteral

Tags: javascript, object, this, object-literal

I'm having a hard time understanding how I could access a `this` located inside one of the methods of an object literal I created.

Here is an example:

```
var app = {
  click: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.saywhat();
  },

  saywhat: function() {  
    console.log('Say what ?');
  }
};

var link = document.querySelector('a');
link.addEventListener('click', app.click);
```

If I click on the link, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.saywhat is not a function`. How can I make `saywhat()` available from inside `click()`? (I would like to find a solution where I'm not forced to use `app.saywhat()`)

Comment: It's because the function is referenced in an event listener, and then called in that context, making `this` inside the function the element, and not the object literal. How a function is defined isn't important when it comes to it's `this` value, it's how it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `this` in event handlers is the element that the event was registered with, i.e, `link`.

In your case, you can use `app.saywhat()`, or you can explicitly specify what to use as `this` by using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). That is,

```
link.addEventListener('click', app.click.bind(app));
```

Comment: Exactly. you **should** use `app.saywhat()`, that would be the only logical thing to do here, since there is only one `app` and it's not something that the OPS instantiated

Comment: @vsync I agree, but in case the OP does have multiple objects, may be calling `app2 = Object.create(app)` or by changing the code to use a constructor, then the bind would be required. That is why I listed both approaches

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind when looking for another solution. Thanks both.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
link.addEventListener('click', app.click.bind(app));
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltu1sso9/)